# The equivalence of almost sure convergence with usual convergence notions in deterministic settings.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

A sequence $\{Z_n\}_{n \geq 1}$ converges almost surely to $Z$ if $P(\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} Z_n = Z) = 1$.

I am trying to understand the object $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} Z_n = Z$.

For a deterministic sequence $\left (a_n \in \mathbb{R}\right )_{n \geq 1}$, I know what $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} a_n = a$ means.

Consider the set $\Omega = \{\omega : P(\omega) > 0 \}$.

$Z_n$ and $Z$ can be thought of as functions $\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$.

In the deterministic setting for convergence of functions $f_n \to f$, we can have either pointwise convergence or uniform convergence.

Is the statement of almost sure convergence connected in some way to pointwise convergence or uniform convergence over the set $\Omega$ where $Z_n$ and $Z$ are viewed as deterministic functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(X,\mathcal M,\mu)$ be a measure space. A function $f:X\to\mathbb R$ is said to be measurable if for any $a,b\in\mathbb R$, $a<b$, the pre-image of $(a,b)$ lies in $\mathcal M$, that is, $f^{-1}((a,b)) = \{x\in X: f(x)\in(a,b)\}$. A sequence of functions $\{f_n\}$ converges **almost everywhere** if there exists a measurable function $f$ and a null set $N$ such that $\lim \limits_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)\mathsf 1_{X\setminus N}(x) = f(x)$, where $\mu(N)=0$.

In the probabilistic setting we have $(\Omega,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$ a probability space (which necessarily satisfies $\mathbb P(\Omega) = 1$. A random variable is a measurable function $X: \Omega \to\mathbb R$, with measurability defined the same way as for an abstract measure space. A sequence of random variables $\{X_n\}$ converges **almost surely** if there exists a random variable $X$ and a null event $E$ such that $\mathbb P\left(\lim \limits_{n\to\infty} X_n\mathsf 1_{\Omega\setminus E}=X\right) = 1$, where $\mathbb P(E)=0$.

These two notions, "almost everywhere" and "almost surely," are the same, just used in different settings.

Comment: I'm not following. Sorry if I'm making an error but in your definition, the functions $f_n$ only converge on a null set which is far from almost everywhere. (Also I presume you want it for all $x$ in which case I'm confused again as your function seems to be $0$ almost everywhere.)

Comment: The measure-theoretic definition for almost-everywhere convergence I know is the following: There exists a limit $f$ with $\mu(f_n \not \to f) = 0$ which of course specializes to the probabilistic notion in a natural way.

Comment: Sorry, I meant $\mathsf 1_{X\setminus N}$ and $\mathsf 1_{\Omega\setminus E}$.

Comment: You should also get rid of the $\mathbb{P}$ in the second part.

Comment: @QiZhu Sorry, I don't know what you're referring to.

Comment: It's the second part that ironX has edited in your post. Though I would certainly also not define it in the way he edited it. So either $\lim_{n \to \infty} X_n \mathbb{1}_{\Omega \setminus E} = X$ or $\mathbb{P} \left( \lim_{n \to \infty} X_n = X \right) = 1$. You of course only typo'ed, so it's not a big deal.

Answer (score 2):

I hope I'm understanding you correctly but it seems like you're confused by the notation. (I also agree that it is easy to be confused by it the first time you come across it.)

It is shorthand for $$\mathbb{P} \left( \{w \in \Omega: \lim_{n \to \infty} Z_n(w) = Z(w) \} \right) = 1.$$